# Formula for the $n^{th}$ root of $n$?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Is there a general formula $r(n)$ to calculate the nth root of $n$, for any complex, irrational, real, etc. $n$?

Sorry for formatting, I’m on mobile.

Comment: Sure.  The formula is $\sqrt[n]{n}$.  You'll have to be a bit more specific about what you want.  Do you want an algorithm to compute a decimal value to a given precision?  (Note that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is not single-valued in general for many values.)

Comment: @BrianTung no, but I have been doing complex roots (for example, ith root of i) and have been wondering if there is a function or method of finding the nth root of n, or things like that; not necessarily decimal values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing specific to $\sqrt[n]n$ compared to $\sqrt[n]m$.

A general formula is

$$\sqrt[n]m=e^{(\log m)/n}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how does the general formula work  for an expression as $\sqrt[3]{-1}$. Maybe it is "limited" for complex numbers?

Comment: @gimusi: you know how complex logarithms work. But I said "a general formula", I didn't say "the most general formula".

Comment: My point is that it doesn't work if we look for example only to integers therefore maybe the use for the general formula would require some discussion. Anyway I don't want to discuss thise details here! Bye

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtons Method to find nth roots recursively to an arbitrary precision.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a formula and not for a numerical method. Does it work also for complex roots?

Answer (score -1):

The big difference is between

- natural, integer, rational, real numbers: for $n>0$ we have that $m=\sqrt[n] n$ is the unique value such that $m^n=n$
- complex number: the solution is not unique, for example for $n>0$ integer $m=\sqrt[n] n$ has $n$ distinct solutions

Comment: For even integer $n>0$ you have **two** real solutions $m$ with $m^n=n,$ therefor $m$ is **not** unique.

Comment: @gammatester I don't know what definition you are referring to bu that's only true only for $n$ even and, as usually defined, in that case $m=\sqrt[n] n$ represent the unique positive value such that $m^n=n$ the negative one is denote as  $m_2=-\sqrt[n] n$. For $n$ odd your claim is never true. Refer also to [Square root definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root)

Comment: That are your words: *that $m$ [...] is the unique value such that $m^n=n$.*  This is obvioulsy wrong if $n$ is an even integer, if you seek real solutions. And it is wrong for all integers $n \ne \pm 1$ if complex solutions are allowed. And if you refer to Wikipedia, why do you not use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Algebraic_formula? And to quote your own comment:
*Anyway I don't want to discuss these details here! Bye*

Comment: @gammatester I'm referring to the usual definition of square root for real numbers. I think that your mixing up different things and making a lot of confusion between different topics. Bye